# Ошибка в коде: задача на нахождение max и min

Tags: pascal

Здравствуйте!

Я только начала изучать Pascal. Дело очень интересное. Но вот моя задача: Мне нужно составить простую программу на нахождение максимального и минимального значения из N введенных чисел.

Вроде бы все сделала правильно. И ошибок компилятор не выдает. Но работает программа не совсем верно.

```
{Программа для определения максимального  и минимального значения из N введенных чисел}

program max_i_min_iz_N;

uses crt;

var N,min,max,a,i,m:integer;

BEGIN
  clrscr;

    repeat

          repeat
             write('Введите любое положительное число: '); readln(N); writeln();
          until(N>0);

          write('Введите ',N,' чисел(-а) через пробел: ');

            i:=2;

            read(a);

            max:=a;
            min:=a;

         repeat
            read(a);
            if(a>max)then max:=a else max:=max;
            if(a<min)then min:=a else min:=min;
            i:=i+1;
         until(i>N);

     writeln();
     writeln('max=',max);
     writeln('min=',min);
     writeln();

  writeln('Для продолжения программы нажмите цифру 1');
  writeln('Для завершения программы нажмите цифру 2'); writeln();
  readln(m);
  writeln();
until(m=2);
END.
```

Вообще программа работает правильно во всех случаях, кроме одного...

Если здесь

```
write('Введите ',N,' чисел(-а) через пробел: ');
```

пользователь вводит значение переменной N = 1, то программа все равно ждет ввода следующей переменной для сравнения.

Я понимаю, что так происходит потому, что у меня в коде прописано дважды считывание переменной **a**, но по-другому сделать у меня не получилось.

Если сделать так:

```
i:=1;
max:=a;
min:=a;
repeat 
read(a);
if(a>max)then max:=a else max:=max;
if(a<min)then min:=a else min:=min;
i:=i+1;
until(i>N);
```

Тогда переменной i присваиваю 1 и дополнительного значения вводить не надо, в этом плане цикл работает правильно. Но находит из введенных значений правильно только максимальное число. Минимальному присваивает 0. Интересно то, что, если программу не закрыть, а продолжить дальше, то тогда программа начинает находить минимальное и максимальное число правильно. Но не из только что введенных значений, а из всех значений, которые были введены.

Если сделать так:

```
i:=1;
read(a);
max:=a;
min:=a;
repeat
    if(a>max)then max:=a else max:=max;
    if(a<min)then min:=a else min:=min;
    i:=i+1;
until(i>N);
```

То здесь программа присваивает первое значение и max, и min, и следующие значения не сравнивает. При этом цикл на повторение программы не срабатывает. Программа просто закрывается и все. В приниципе, понятно, почему не сравнивает значения, ведь в следующем цикле учавствует только одно и то же значение переменной а, которое было введено первым. А вот почему тогда программа закрывается сама, не считывая переменную m?

В общем, я отказалась от идеи использовать только одно считывание переменной N. Но только тогда как можно сделать так, чтобы программа в случае ввода цифры 1 для переменной N все работало правильно? Может быть просто добавить для 1 конструкцию case?

Еще мне не очень нравиться i:=2; Не красиво как-то что ли. Привычнее видеть i:=1; Но если я присваиваю переменной i значение 1, то программа запрашивает для сравнения введенных значений на одно больше.

Но вообще стукаюсь глазами и не вижу, что делаю не так.

Не сочтите за труд, подскажите, пожалуйста, где я ошибаюсь.

Comment: Не дело девушкам программированием заниматься...Вы бы лучше детей там растили( В крайнем случае на кухню шли ). Ну не как не в "Пэскале" копались :DDDD. Это не дискриминация по половому признаку...И я не ненавижу женщин...И вообще я не зануда %)))))

Comment: Сразу виден восточный мужчина.

Comment: Девушкам нужно изучать программирование по трем причинам
- она планирует стать женой умного мужчины (программирование развивает).
- она планирует хорошо воспитать детей.
- ей это интересно.

Comment: @kovadim первые две причины неадекватны... :DDDD

Comment: Тут стОит вопрос поставить шире: имеет ли женщина право заниматься техникой, наукой, искусством, бизнесом, вообще работать где-то или она должна только сидеть дома, готовить обеды и воспитывать детей. Программирование - один из вариантов занятий "вне дома", если конкретная женщина имеет к этому способности и желание. А программированием и многим мужчинам не стоит заниматься.

Comment: Дико извиняюсь, синтаксис pascal не помню (пишу на C), но алгоритмы почти всюду одинаковы.

Самое простое начать с i := 1 и поместить во внутренний repeat после read(a)

    if (i=1) then begin max := a; min := a; end;

а дальше как у Вас написано.  

Во внешнем repeat напишите i := 1, а read(a), min := a и max := a выбросите. Ну, и конечно, else в if для min и max не нужны.

Comment: @mikillskegg +1 Дя...Но женщина должна растить детей и следить за домом...Ибо кроме них это не кто не сделает...А вот программы и мужчины написать могут :DDDD

Comment: Это, конечно, каждая пара должна сама решать, но вот моя жена очень любит свою науку. И успешно ею занимается. И я даю ей возможность ею заниматься. Не хочу ее видеть несчастной. Мы прекрасно разделили обязанности и у нас полная гармония и взаимопонимание. А мужчина, который не может помыть посуду или сварить суп, не вызывает у меня уважения. 

Кстати, было бы интересно прочитать мнение автора вопроса )))

Comment: Всем огромное спасибо за внимание, которое Вы проявили к моему вопросу! Ваши советы я, безусловно, учла:) Мой уровень, конечно, пока что еще начинающий, НО мне очень приятно иметь возможность общаться с людьми, имеющими не малый опыт в программировании.

Comment: Вот, что получилось в результате, с учетом Ваших советов :)

Comment: program MaxMinIzN;
uses crt;
var N,min,max,a,i,m:integer;
BEGIN
clrscr;
repeat
 write('Введите положительное число: '); readln(N);
 if (N<=0) then writeln('Число ',N,' не положительное')
 else begin write('Введите ',N,' число(-ла,-ел) через пробел: ');
 i:=1;
  repeat
   read(a);
   if (i=1) then begin max := a; min := a; end;
   if(a>max)then max:=a;
   if(a<min)then min:=a;
   i:=i+1;
  until(i>N);
writeln('max=',max);
writeln('min=',min);
end;
writeln('Для продолжения программы нажмите цифру 1');
writeln('Для завершения программы нажмите цифру 2');
readln(m);
until(m=2);
END.

Comment: Вы уж простите, пожалуйста, за сплошную строку кода, но в комментариях по другому написать не получается.

Comment: По поводу вопроса о том, дело девушкам заниматься программированием или не дело скажу так. Долго ли Вы вытяните, если Вас посадят на кухню вместе с детьми? А если так каждый день? Да терпения не хватит! Проверено на собственном муже. Почему Вы считаете вполне полноправным запихнуть нас на кухню, посадить в доме, повесить на нас домашние дела? Особенно с учетом того, что это рутинно и не так легко, как кажется на первый взгляд. Вы скажите, не мужское это дело заниматься домашними делами! А между прочим, без мужской руки в доме уюта нет.

Comment: А кто сказал, что программирование именно мужское дело? Особенно учитывая то, что первым программистом была Ада Лавлейс. Я полностью согласна с @mikillskegg Нужно уметь разделять обязанности, вместе заниматься домашними делами, тогда и дом действительно превратиться в уютный семейный очаг, который создали вместе, в который хочется вернуться, в котором хочется быть. И так же согласна с тем, что нужно уважать интересы друг друга. Не спорю, у многих мужчин получается отлично программировать, но и не нужно рубить на корню желание женщин заниматься этим.

Comment: Я вам поражаюсь... Зачем было кормить троля?..

Троль вышел на обед, вы ему все дружно - на трольчик, кушай, приятного апетита ^.^

Comment: @AlexWindHope, не турбуйся, все горазд!

Comment: Девушка должна быть девушкой, а парень - парнем, только и всего) Если девушку программирование не превращает в бледное красноглазое существо с кружкой пива в потертом свитере, а парня готовка еды и сидение с детьми в вечно ноющую мямлю "килограмм 120 при росте в 170" - дык в путь, значит, все хорошо) Но разделять, хоть и не в этом случае, надо - я своей девушке банально запрещу работать рельсоукладчиком или строителем, как бы ей этого ни хотелось. Точнее, не то что запрещу, просто `(моя_девушка XOR рельсоукладчик)`, как-то так) Ну и в остальном солидарен с @mikillskegg #2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Первое, что бросается в глаза - это такие строки:

```
 if(a>max)then max:=a else max:=max;
 if(a<min)then min:=a else min:=min;
```

Их точно можно записать короче:

```
 if(a>max)then max:=a;
 if(a<min)then min:=a;
```

Функционал тот же, а глазу приятнее.
Теперь перейдем к самому главному. К этому циклу

```
repeat
  read(a);
  if(a>max)then max:=a else max:=max;
  if(a<min)then min:=a else min:=min;
  i:=i+1;
until(i>N);
```

Его можно записать красивее:

```
while(i <= N) do begin
  read(a);
  if(a>max)then max:=a;
  if(a<min)then min:=a;
  i:=i+1;
end;
```

И все должно работать.

Если не нравится `i := 2;` то можно заменить на `i := 1;`, но нужно ещё одно изменение - `while(i <= N)` заменить на `while(i < N)`.

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы прога не мотала цикл, нужно вложенный Repeat заменить на While так:

```
            i:=1;

            Write('a = ');
            read(a);
            max:=a;
            min:=a;

            While (i<N) Do // если ввести 1, цикл работать не будет
              Begin
                Write('a = ');
                read(a);
                if(a>max)then max:=a;
                if(a<min)then min:=a;
                i:=i+1;
              End;
```

Или написать такое условие после первого вложенного цикла Repeat:

```
If (N=1) Then Break;
```

Но, я бы сделал так: изменил бы условие на цикле:

```
repeat
  write('Введите любое положительное число: '); readln(N); writeln;
until(N>1);
```

Сразу от пользователя ввод положительного числа требовать.
Тогда и счётчику i:=1 единичку присвоить можно.

Answer (score 1):

Еще совет: не спешите переписывать и дописывать свой код. Ошибки компиляции ищутся просто, а логические ошибки намного сложнее.

> А я уж начала и case добавлять и через while и for писать программу.

Все циклы взаимозаменяемые и лучше разобраться для начала нормально хотя бы с одним:) настолько огромная программа) я бы написал так:

```
Program max_i_min_iz_N;
var
i, n, a, max: LongInt;
begin
   write('Введите количество чисел: ');
   readln(N);
   max := MaxLongInt;
   min := -MaxLongInt;
   for i := 1 to N do
   begin
      write('Введите ',i,'-oе число: ');
      readln(a);
      if a > max then max := a;
      if a < min then min := a;
   end;
   writeln('Max = ', max);
   writeln('Min = ', min);
end.
```

MaxLongInt - зарезервированная переменная во FreePascal, советую писать на нем.
MaxLongInt = 2147483648 - максимальное число, которое влазит в тип LongInt
FreePascal может испугать досовским окошком, по сравнению с ABC:) но в нем можно выделять намного больше памяти.. Если кратко, то Pascal ABC для детей:)

Comment: забыл в конце
readln;
но не суть:)

Answer (score 0):

[[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp), благодарю за дельный совет! Действительно, все гениальное просто :) Добавлена всего одна строчка => и программа работает как надо :) А я уж начала и case добавлять и через while и for писать программу. Оказывается ответ лежал на поверхности :) Еще раз Вам огромное спасибо и удачи Вам, [[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp) !

Comment: И Вам, Елена, успехов и множества **victory**.

Comment: Как же эти victory особенно нужны мне сейчас:) Спасибо за пожелание :)